# How to find a folder name which includes today's date?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check if there is a folder where the name includes today's date.

The path looks like;

> B:\NOS\EIhracat\Credit\2022\34- 17.09.2022\Nakit List.xlsx

There are a lot of subfolders with a name that looks like "34- 17.09.2022" or "15- 16.09.2022" etc. under Years.
The numbers before the date are changing randomly.

How can I find the folder name which ends with today's date (or starts with today's date. I can move the numbers after date).

I tried this.

```vb
dtToday = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
dtYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")
Ihracat = "B:\NOS\EIhracat\Credit\" & dtYear & "\"

strFileName = Ihracat & "*dtToday & "\" & "Nakit List.xlsx"
strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)

If strFileExists = "" Then
    MsgBox "Can't find!"
Else
```

Comment: Is "B:\NOS\EIhracat\Credit\2022\" **always** the path of the folder where the one containing the required `Date` exists`?

Comment: Yes, always B:\NOS\EIhracat\Credit\2022\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next function. If works if you know **the folder where the searched one containing `Date` in its name exists**:

```
Function getFoldPath(dirFolder As String, strToFind As String) As String
    Dim fldName As String
    If Right(dirFolder, 1) <> "\" Then dirFolder = dirFolder & "\"
    fldName = Dir(dirFolder & "*" & strToFind & "*", vbDirectory)

    Do While fldName <> ""
        If fldName <> "." And fldName <> ".." Then
            ' Use bitwise comparison to make sure dirFolder is a directory.
            If (GetAttr(dirFolder & fldName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                getFoldPath = dirFolder & fldName: Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        fldName = Dir
    Loop
End Function
```

You can call the function in the next way:

```
Sub testGetFoldPath_()
    Const parentFolder As String = "B:\NOS\EIhracat\Credit\2022\" 'take care of the ending backslash ("\")
    Debug.Print getFoldPath(parentFolder, CStr(Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")))
End Sub
```